# Changing part of a image url every x amount of seconds

Tags: javascript, php, html

Alright so my question today is bit of a weird one. Basically what I'm trying to do is take this image code

```
<img src="3d.php?a=-25&w=35&wt=-45&abg=0&abd=-30&ajg=-25&ajd=30&ratio=13&format=png&displayHairs=true&headOnly=false&login=">
```

and have it update only the w=35 part of it and have it add +1 to that number, either forever or until it hits 360 then resets it to 0, every x amount of seconds.

The point of this is to create what looks like a spinning image, instead of spawning each possible wt= from 0 to 360 by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<img id="threedee">
```

In your script, further down the page:

```
var w = 35;
var x = 5; // every 5 seconds
var threedee = document.getElementById("threedee");
setInterval(function () {
    w = (w + 1) % 360;
    var src = "3d.php?a=-25&w=" + w + "&wt=-45&abg=0&abd=-30&ajg=-25&";
    src += "ajd=30&ratio=13&format=png&displayHairs=true&headOnly=false&login=";
    threedee.src = src;
}, x * 1000);
```

Comment: That worked wonderfully, just how I wanted it to work. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
var counter = 35;
var x = 5;
var url = '3d.php?a=-25&w={{counter}}&wt=-45&abg=0&abd=-30&ajg=-25&ajd=30&ratio=13&format=png&displayHairs=true&headOnly=false&login='

setInterval(function(){
    img.src = url.replace('{{counter}}',counter);
    counter = counter + 1 > 360 ? 0 :  counter + 1;
},x * 1000);
```